# Applying git commits to working tree unadded?

Tags: git

Suppose I have a linear git history of 8 commits and one branch (master):

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> [8=master]
```

I want to move master to 4 (which I can do with `git branch -f master 4`):

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> [4=master] -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8
```

Now the working tree is in state 4.

I now want to apply the changes from `4 -> 8` to my working tree as a patch.

That is, without effecting the state of the .git folder I want to apply the changes from `4->8` unstaged to my working tree.  After this the working tree should be in state 8 but the committed state and master branch should be in state 4.

Another way to say it: Pretend after moving master to 4, I made the changes from 4->8 manually to my working tree without adding them to the index.  The result should be the same.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 25):

I know I'm late to the party, but for other's reference, I think the simplest way is:

`git cherry-pick --no-commit 4..8`

Comment: Plus `git reset` after that to get changes unstaged.

Answer (score 6):

```
git format-patch 4..8 | xargs git apply
```

[edit: this next one from the comment below skips making individual patch files]

```
git diff 4..8 | git apply
```

Comment: Or, equally, `git diff 4..8 | git apply`

Answer (score 2):

In your case, if you don't actually care about the "unstaged" bit, the simplest thing to do is probably

```
git checkout 8 -- .
```

This will update your tree and index to match that of commit 8, without changing your commit history. You can then `git reset` to discard the index changes.

If you truly do wish to leave the index file undisturbed, it's slightly more complicated, as git always updates the working tree from the index. You could do something like

```
GIT_INDEX_FILE=/tmp/foo git checkout 8 -- .
```

This will use the path `/tmp/foo` as a temporary index file just for this command. You may then want to delete this file afterwards.

---

In a more complicated situation where you want to reapply patches that wouldn't actually bring you back to the precise state of commit 8, you can use `git cherry-pick --no-commit commit1 commit2 ...` to apply the commits in sequence. This will still modify the index of course.

Comment: Beware that if you had renamed a file in that commit, it seems the `git checkout 8 -- .` will create the new file in the index but not delete the old one. I just got caught out by that.

Answer (score 1):

Making OP's state happen:

```
cyclone% mkdir myrepo
cyclone% cd myrepo
cyclone% git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/myrepo/.git/
cyclone% echo 'Hello, world!' >hello
cyclone% git add hello
cyclone% git commit -m 'Initial import'
[master (root-commit) 6ec97b1] Initial import
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 hello
cyclone% echo 'How are you?' >>hello
cyclone% git add hello
cyclone% git commit -m "Added 'How are you?'"
[master 8786161] Added 'How are you?'
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
# Now, if I reset back, the commit object
# seems to be removed (possibly due to my current
# version of Git vs. OP's older version?). To prevent
# this, I'll "name" the commit OP considers '8'.
# Thus, OP would put the commit ID corresponding
# to their '8' wherever I put 'tip'.
cyclone% git branch tip
# In all my years, I've never heard of
# 'git branch --force' -- then again, I'm not
# Linus Torvalds, so I guess I know only like
# half of Git, as do all of you (unless you ARE
# Linus Torvalds). Nonetheless, if I try the next,
# commented-out line, I get:
#     fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.
#git branch -f master 'HEAD^'
# A (too?) quick Google doesn't really help on the
# matter, so... In the undying words of...
# well, somebody-or-other in the whole long history
# of ever: Lemme fix that for ya...
cyclone% git update-ref HEAD 'HEAD^'
# Now this is the crucial point: If this is going
# to be easy, you need a recent enough version of
# Git to support 'git restore', because that DOES
# make things easy (see below).
cyclone% git restore --staged .
# Now, this is actually the state OP wants, but
# since they are at a different state, I guess we'll
# wantonly destroy it...
cyclone% git checkout .
Updated 1 path from the index
```

With this, we are at OP's state:

```
# We are on master, with no changes (staged nor unstaged)
# and master is the "old" commit:
cyclone% git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
# The working tree reflects the "old" commit:
cyclone% cat hello
Hello, world!
# Commit '8' (i.e. 'tip') reflects the "new"
# commit:
cyclone% git show tip:hello
Hello, world!
How are you?
```

So, now comes the one simple command that brings OP's current state to OP's desired state:

```
cyclone% git restore --source=tip .
```

Now we're exactly where we want to be:

```
# The changes between '4' and '8' are present, but
# not staged nor committed:
cyclone% git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   hello

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
# The current branch (master, as Git tells us above) is on
# what OP considers '4':
cyclone% git log
commit f4661e0c12a20acb6dd0bc4afe8c9b2301667608 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Simon "UncleSniper" Bausch <(REDACTED)>
Date:   (no matter)

    Initial import
# The working tree includes the changes between '4'
# and '8':
cyclone% cat hello
Hello, world!
How are you?
# The changes between '4' and '8' are "present" (see
# above), but neither staged nor committed:
cyclone% git diff
diff --git a/hello b/hello
index af5626b..b076fc1 100644
--- a/hello
+++ b/hello
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 Hello, world!
+How are you?
# In fact, nothing is staged at all:
cyclone% git diff --cached
cyclone%
```

So yeah, there is exactly one command (`git restore --source=tip .`) between OP's current state and OP's desired state -- assuming a recent enough  version of Git.

Comment: To address the comments in your answer that I edited out: Posting up to date answers to add new information that's not covered in other answers, is absolutely fine, and even recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```
 git checkout master@{1} -- .
```

is all you need. It reads "checkout the files that the commit that master was pointing to one time ago". Checkout `git reflog` to see how this works.

Also, you should not be forcefully re-making the branch as you did. This will allow git to track all the places that master used to be pointing to. Use

```
git stash -u
```

in case you have some work in the work dir. Then

```
git reset --hard master^^^^
```

or

```
git reset --hard master~4
```

Comment: _"This will allow git to track all the places that master used to be pointing to."_ - how do you mean?  Could you explain this tracking a little more?

Comment: He said he wanted to apply the changes unstaged.  Checkout will stage them.

Answer (score 0):

```
git cherry-pick master~4 master~5 master~6 master~7 master~8
```

Your working tree has to be clean though

```
git help cherry-pick
```